# nginx doesn't acess folders inside static folder (django app)

Tags: django, nginx

I searched and didn't find this exact problem.

I deployed an application in django on GCP, using gunicorn + nginx

It's working normally, except for the static files

I ran django's collectstatic and got the files folder and statics like this:

```
lnmat@sistema-ag:~/app_repo$ ls
apps gunicorn-error-log requirements.txt static venv
base_static manage.py sistema_vendas_ag templates 
lnmat@sistema-ag:~/app_repo$ cd static
lnmat@sistema-ag:~/app_repo/static$ ls
admin global 
lnmat@sistema-ag:~/app_repo/static$ ls admin
css fonts img js 
lnmat@sistema-ag:~/app_repo/static$ ls global
css js vendor
```

In the nginx error log:

```
2022/12/13 20:36:00 [error] 8136#8136: *1 open() "/home/lnmat/app_repo/static/js/sb-admin-2.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: -, request: "GET /static/js/sb-admin-2.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x", referrer: "http://x.x.x.x/login/?next=/"
2022/12/13 20:36:09 [error] 8136#8136: *7 open() "/home/lnmat/app_repo/static/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: -, request: "GET /static/css/sb-admin-2.min.css HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x", referrer: "http://x.x.x.x/"
2022/12/13 20:36:09 [error] 8136#8136: *12 open() "/home/lnmat/app_repo/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: -, request: "GET /static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x", referrer: "http://x.x.x.x/"
```

Apparently nginx is trying to access the static files directly in the main folder without accessing the subfolders global/ and admin/ which is where the files are.

My nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/lnmat/app_repo/static/;
    }

}
```

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'base_static',
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
```

I don't know what it could be, any suggestions?

[EDIT]

My static tags in template:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static 'css/sb-admin-2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
```

My base_static folder:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwXtr.png)

Comment: In your `base_static` folder are your static files contained in a folder named `global`? Can you show the `{% static %}` tag in your template where you reference these files?

Comment: Your static files are contained in a folder named `global`, you need to include this in the static tag - `{% static 'global/css/sb-admin-2.min.css' %}`

Comment: I can't believe it was just that! thanks!